# Included angle in a semicircle

Tags: statics

I'm solving this problem in mechanics,

Two cylinders A and B, weighing 100 lb and 200 lb respectively, are connected by a rigid rod curved parallel to the smooth cylindrical surface shown in Fig. P-329. Determine the angles α and β that define the position of equilibrium.

[image: Fig. P-329]

I already understood that the relation between $\beta$ and $\alpha$ is  $\cos \alpha = 2 \cos \beta$ by doing summation of moment with respect to O and equating to 0. What I don't get is how come the angle from this picture becomes 90 degrees?

[image]

Comment: That's given by the question. If you pay attention to the original image, you'll see that the internal angle ($180-\alpha-\beta$) has the classic right-angle symbol.

Comment: Sorry. I didnt see it. Too small. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's given by the question. If you pay attention to the original image, you'll see that the internal angle ($180−\alpha−\beta$) has the classic right-angle symbol.

[image]
<sup>[Source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6c/Right_angle.svg/1200px-Right_angle.svg.png)</sup>